# Does it make sense to nuke the whole planet as a country if you get nuked and you don't know which country nuked you?

Tags: armed-conflict, nuclear-weapons

Does it make sense to nuke the whole planet as a country if you get nuked and you don't know which country nuked you?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction

> Mutual assured destruction (MAD) is a doctrine of military strategy
> and national security policy which posits that a full-scale use of
> nuclear weapons by an attacker on a nuclear-armed defender with
> second-strike capabilities would cause the complete annihilation of
> both the attacker and the defender.[1] It is based on the theory of
> rational deterrence, which holds that the threat of using strong
> weapons against the enemy prevents the enemy's use of those same
> weapons. **The strategy is a form of Nash equilibrium in which, once
> armed, neither side has any incentive to initiate a conflict or to
> disarm.**

I was wondering if it makes any logical sense to consider the rest of the world as the attacker when you don't know which country attacked you, and even knowing which country attacked whether it makes sense to still attack every country with nukes. I am thinking that it's not the case, or it's a bit more complicated than that, but I am not sure.

Comment: Is there anyone saying the 'whole planet' will be involved? Or that a country's policies is to consider 'the rest of the world as the attacker'? Your quote mentions that the MAD doctrine believes in "annihilation of both the attacker and the defender", which seems much more limited.

Comment: The only thing that it might make sense to nuke at some point in the somewhat foreseeable future is an incoming asteroid.

Comment: Are you seriously asking if there's *A LOGICAL SENSE* to do what is essentially a murder-suicide on a national level?

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov did you mean to say "on a global level"?

Comment: Voting to close - Your question is based on faulty assumptions. MAD doesn't mean that if you do not know who bombed you, bomb everyone else. Please read up on MAD, and if you still feel confused about it, please cite the research and update your question.

Comment: it really depends on how screwed your country is, if it was only a limited exchange or even a single nuke then no it doesn't make sense to destroy the world over that, however if it was total atomic annihilation and your county isn't recovering over that, then all bets are off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Western theories of nuclear strategy are heavily influenced by game theory. In much of game theory, you assign values to possible outcomes and then try to find a strategy which optimizes the value of your outcome under conditions where probabilities are unknown. Think of the well-known Prisoner's Dilemma, where a prisoner tries to minimize prison time. As the Dilemma is put, it does not care about reputation among other criminals, it *only* looks at sentencing.

So if your value function considers all outcomes where you get nuked equally bad, then 'indiscriminate retaliation' makes sense.

Also, in practice, there are few nuclear-armed countries in conflict with the entire rest of the world. Consider how during the Cuban Missile Crisis, President Kennedy [declared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_Missile_Crisis#Speech_to_the_nation) that the Soviets would be held responsible for any missile launched from Cuba, despite Cuba being a sovereign country which could have gone to war with the US without involving the Soviets.

Comment: A strange game. The only winning move is not to play.

Comment: Cuba did not possess its own indigenous missile manufacturing capabilities. The missiles deployed in Cuba were supplied by the Soviet Union as part of a strategic decision during the Cold War.

Comment: @Whysoserious the Soviet Union having supplied the missiles does not mean that the Soviet Union controlled the missiles.  Is a supermarket or a farmer responsible for the egg on my car?

Comment: @phoog it was an arrangement roughly similar to NATO nuclear sharing - USSR provided the missiles, the launchers, the operators and the guards, Cuba provided the land for the base. So the "store-bought egg" analogy doesn't quite apply. It is possible that with time Cuba would become able to launch a missile attack at USA without Soviet participation, but in 1962 it would be Soviet military personnel at the controls, not Cubans.